# Meaning of "hinterlassen" in old German marriage record

Tags: germany, marriage-records, 17th-century

I found an early 17th century German marriage record in which the groom is marked as "hinterlassen" in reference to his father. Does that give me information about the father's date of death? In particular, can I infer that he was dead when the son was born, or is "hinterlassen" strictly with reference to the wedding?

Comment: Are you able to include an image of that part of this marriage record?

Comment: Assumed wording "hinterlassener Sohn" is German for "surviving son" (hinterlassen = left behind). We really should have an image or more complete transcript of the entry to ensure other nuances aren't missed.

Answer (score 2):

Hinterlassen means "leave" or "left behind."  Really need a more complete transcript.  I suspect that the father was deceased at the time of the wedding.